# Static Web Application hosted in Amazon S3 Bucket suddenly not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, lets-encrypt

The hosted application worked until yesterday but suddenly not working today.

What I have done?

1. Using Cloudfront - To host my website from Amazon’s edge locations with a custom SSL certificate setup for my domain.
2. Amazon
   Certificate Manager - To get HTTPS Certificate

Hosted my client application in S3. They wanted to access their site using a domain name. To achieve this I have provided two records as given below.

```
Type    Host   Value                         TTL
A       @      IP of the client domain       600

CNAME   www    CloudFront distribution URL   600
```

The thing is Endpoint which I got while configuring Cloudfront **"d3ajo2v2g7lf33.cloudfront.net"** is working but the domain name which I added as an alias to this endpoint is not working.

**Probable findings from my side:**

1) Used let's encrypt to get the SSL and it's about to expire within a week.

2) Added A record with the IP address of the domain. As am using Cloudfront am doubting that the domain does not have a static IP.

> Also please let me know CloudFront distribution domain name IP will change every time or will it be static.

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront has CNAME record as well. So you have to register your domain name in the CloudFront distribution.

as for the SSL certificate for your custom domain, take a look at [AWS ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/). It may be easier than using lets encrypt certificate (your call).

and yes. use the cloudfront's domain URL. it won't change unless you delete the distribution.

Comment: Thanks, @kkesley. Need to know whether the IP address for the Cloud Distribution domain name is static or dynamic. If it is dynamic how to add this domain IP as A record ??

Comment: @VijayRajendiran CloudFront does not have a specific IP address. It only has domain name for you to refer. I guess you can find the IP address when you do a domain lookup. However, I don't think it's guaranteed to be the same as AWS may change it for any cases. You need to use CNAME record rather than A record.